# How do I apply modifiers and other changes in 2.90?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, mirror

I'm using 2.90, and going through a tutorial to create a couch on youtube. I've added a mirror modifier, 2 arrays, and a subdiv. How do I apply those modifiers so it completes those operations on the mesh? I don't see an Apply button anywhere, and have looked up 'Apply' in the doc with no answer. Is there a hotkey other than Ctrl-A?

Comment: Ctrl+A in viewport will provide a menu with Visual Geometry to Mesh option which does the same as what Convert to > Mesh does. Or use addons like Modifier List which still have Apply button as normal button (besides other useful things)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know it had to be in Object Mode for the Apply button in Modifier panel dropdown to be clickable.

Answer (score 3):

While Emir's answer is technically correct, it can be tedious to apply multiple modifiers using the Modifier's panel. Note  that, for any selected object, you can also float your cursor anywhere within a given modifier's listing within the Modifier panel and press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd> shortcut, and that specific modifier will be applied instantly. Which is nice.

But if you have a lot of modifiers this may still not be very convenient. Thankfully, you can apply all modifiers at once by selecting the object which contains them in Object Mode, and at the top of the 3D View, go to the *Object* menu, then [*Convert To*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/convert.html?#mesh), and finally **Mesh**. Even though the mesh was already a mesh before you began, converting it to mesh applies all its modifiers at once.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that, helpful for future reference. Is there a drawback to using it instead of Apply / Ctrl-A?

Comment: Not that I know of. Though it will always apply ALL modifiers, so if you only want ONE modifier applied, while you happen to have more than one modifier currently, then you wouldn't want to use the "Convert To" method. It also may be more convenient in general to just use the Ctrl+A method in most ordinary cases, since your modifier stack can be persistently in view much of the time, while the Convert To menu must always be dug up before use.

Answer (score 2):

There is a dropdown menu, here is an image:

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your response. I didn't see it there before somehow, and it was greyed out because I was in Edit Mode. I didn't know it had to be in Object Mode to be clickable / functional.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the modifiers pannel  you will see an arrow if you hit that you will see an option applly
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Somehow I hadn't seen it, possibly because it was greyed out since I was in Edit Mode. It has to be in Object Mode for it to be clickable.